# how to excecute a simple oracle procedure with out parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I am new to oracle procedures so I'm having a bit of trouble with this. I have an oracle procedure defined like

```
PROCEDURE USERPROGRESS (
queryType IN varchar2,
o_Cursor OUT cur_Cursor) IS ...
```

Notice how it has the out cur_Cursor. At the end of the procedure the procedure does

```
OPEN o_Cursor FOR sql_string;
```

How exactly do I can I call this procedure? I'm having trouble finding any helpful examples. Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of cur_Cursor? It must be a ref cursor but is it stongly or weakly typed? Are you calling it from another pl/sql procedure or from another language like java? If so, which language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link..

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/UsingRefCursorsToReturnRecordsets.php

Depending on how you declared cur_Cursor, you can define a variable in your procedure and then fetch and display the results as needed.